# React error: octal literals are not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, calculator, octal

so i am creating a calculator in react with this code

```
   
   setMyDisplay((elem)=>{
     
  return elem += event.target.className
})

   if(event.target.id ==='equals'){
     setMyDisplay(eval(myDisplay))
   }
   else if(event.target.id === 'clear'){
     setMyDisplay(0)
   }
   
   
   console.log(eval(myDisplay))
}
```

the code works fine until I press the clear button and it resets myDisplay state to 0. when I type values again the 0 does not go away. how can I fix this

Comment: a) don't use `eval` for a calculator b) reset your display to the empty string, not `0`.

Comment: thank you, I changed it and it now works properly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.